# Problem involving Quasi-Newton Methods of nonlinear optimization

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Can someone help me get started on this problem? It involves Quasi-Newton Methods of nonlinear optimization.

[image: Heres the problem]

If any more information is needed, I can submit more.